# Make Grease pencil renders independent of World Lighting

Tags: light, grease-pencil, world

Grease Pencil renders are darker when World Lighting is On .

World Lighting can be switched off if **'SceneWorld' is toggled off**.
However this action  then doesn't render the World Background.

Tried changing **Color Management to Standard** but no change.

Also used **Camera Ray output from Light Path node to affect the GreasePencil render**  but since it is not a MESH ,still no change.

Is there any way to make GreasePencil renders independent of SceneWorld lighting.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If your colours look weird in render preview then follow any one of the given solutions(solution 2 recommended)**

This issue is caused by the ***'use lights'*** option, this option is used if you have light sources close to your drawing to affect the colour.

**SOLUTION 1:**

In the layers panel, you'll need to uncheck ***"use lights"*** at the bottom of the layers list, for each layer, just under the blend mode and opacity.

*****OBJECT DATA PROPERTIES**>select one layer at a time>uncheck the use lights option(under the opacity slider).***

**NOTE:**    ***Uncheck the 'use lights' option in all your layers or else this method won`t work***

**SOLUTION 2:**

Another easier way instead of unchecking the option in all the layers instead of selecting them one by one is by selecting your grease pencil>*****OBJECT PROPERTIES**>visibility>uncheck 'use lights' grease pencil.****

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This worked for me:

1. Select the object.
2. Go in to object properties.
3. Unchek "Use Lights" under visibility.